# Authorize not working in API with ASP.NET Core Identity and JWT Token

Tags: authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-8

I need emergency nelp ... I'm using ASP.NET Core 8.0 and this is my `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer(); 
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();   
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>
             (optn => optn.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer")));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<UserIdentityCustom,IdentityRole>(opt =>
        {
            opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; //eror
            opt.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(100, 1, 1, 1);
            opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;               
        })  
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()                                      
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(option =>
        {
            option.SaveToken = true;
            option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey  
                (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:IssuerSigningKey"]))
            };
        });

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

This is my controller and action method (have `[Authorize]`):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UploadController : ControllerBase
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Uploadtest()
    {
        return Ok("Uploaded !");
    }
}
```

The JWT token will be created by this action method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UsersLoginModel model) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {        
        ResultIdentity = True; //ResultIdentity = Check By UserMannager

        if (ResultIdentity.Succeeded == true) 
        {
            var key = _config["JWT:IssuerSigningKey"]; 
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            var tokenObject = new JwtSecurityToken(
                claims: new List<Claim>() {new Claim("id", model.Username)},
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));

            var ResultJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenObject);

            if (ResultJwt == null) 
                return Unauthorized();

            return Ok(ResultJwt);
        }
    }

    return Unauthorized();
}
```

The response is always an error HTTP 404 or HTTP 302 (I tested in TalentApiTester - Swagger - Postman...)

What is the problem? I tried for 5 hours...

This is my test :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "Always Response is this : 200-"Uploaded !"    ? Is it 200 ok ? So what's problem  ? Does it work fine ?

Comment: @QingGuo sory it was not 200 - edited

Comment: have you try to add token in Authorization in postman ?  like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW3Qv.png  and contentype : text/plain; charset=utf-8

Comment: @QingGuo yes, its not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add "Issuer","Audience" in Jwt,
have a try to modify the code like below:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(option =>
        {
            option.SaveToken = true;
            option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey  
                (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:IssuerSigningKey"]))
            };
        });
```

Then modify like below :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UsersLoginModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {        
        ResultIdentity = True; //ResultIdentity = Check By UserMannager
        if (ResultIdentity.Succeeded == true) 
        { 
            var issuer =  _config["Jwt:Issuer"];
            var audience =  _config["Jwt:Audience"];
            var key = _config["JWT:IssuerSigningKey"]; 
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
 var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
 {
     Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
     { new Claim("id", model.Username) 
     }),
     Expires= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),
     Issuer = issuer,
     Audience = audience,
     SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
     
 };
 var tokenObject = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var ResultJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenObject);
            if (ResultJwt == null) return Unauthorized();
            return Ok(ResultJwt);
        }
       
    }
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Oh My god it was The problem I was dealing with for hours ... Infact [ValidateIssuer] and [ValidateAudience] Default are true. I did not write them and thought they were false... just need ValidateIssuer = false , ValidateAudience=false ... Thanks